# Exposing A datasource as a service in WSO2 Integration studio

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I am trying to expose a RDBMS datasource as a service. And I am trying to connect to a MSSQL (SQL Server) database. But I am getting the error "Connection failed Could not connect to database" when I try to test the connection to the database.

My Configuration:

[image]

---

Connection Error while trying to test the connection:

[image]

Do you have any ideas why I am getting this error.
Note: I have created a ms sql db server instance using docker container and I can access this through the ssms by giving the user credentials without any issues. (i.e) localhost 1433 server, Username : SA and the relevent password).

I was expecting to connect to the DB without any issue. And I was following the tutorials given in the link: https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/tutorials/integration-tutorials/sending-a-simple-message-to-a-datasource/

**Error**

```
ERROR {DBDeployer} - The data-1.0.0.dbs service, which is not valid, caused {1} DS Fault Message: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target". ClientConnectionId:1ac75219-318a-4126-930e-3fdc6a82721d DS Code: CONNECTION_UNAVAILABLE_ERRO
```

Comment: Just ignore this error DB config page and deploy the service. And then try to invoke the service. If you get a error when invoking,  add the error trace you get to the question.

Comment: @ycr Hi. Thank you for the Reply. I did as you told but it gives the below error.

ERROR {DBDeployer} - The data-1.0.0.dbs service, which is not valid, caused {1} DS Fault Message: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. 

Error: "PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target". ClientConnectionId:1ac75219-318a-4126-930e-3fdc6a82721d

DS Code: CONNECTION_UNAVAILABLE_ERROR

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that you are missing the MSSQL certificate in the client's trustore. Hence try importing the MSSQL Public certificate to WSO2 trustore. Take a look at this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/configuring-the-client-for-ssl-encryption?view=sql-server-ver16#configuring-the-client-trust-store) for more details.

```
keytool -import -alias <alias> -keystore  $IS_HOME/repository/resources/security/client-trustore.jks -file mssql.cer
```

Also you can try disabling SSL verification(not recommended) by adding the following properties to the connection URL.

```
encrypt=false;trustServerCertificate=false;
```