# Exposing a MS SQL database as a service in wso2 integration studio

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I followed the tutorial link which uses mysql given below to and it worked without any issues.

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/tutorials/integration-tutorials/sending-a-simple-message-to-a-datasource/

Now I want to connect to a database in sql server. Preferably the database "ExersizesData" which is in the database server "DESKTOP-ITFNIJS\SQLEXPRESS".

[See Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxRH2.png)

I cannot understand how to construct the URL for connecting to this database.

[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWL22.png)

When I try to use it like this (see the screenshot below). It gives connection failed. Could not connect to the database error.

[see here1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWt7s.png)
[see here2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7J9lS.png)

Please help me resolve this issue. Appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exposing A datasource as a service in WSO2 Integration studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75786805/exposing-a-datasource-as-a-service-in-wso2-integration-studio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is when connecting to SQL Express. SQL Express runs as a separate instance. For example, the Connection String value should have - [SERVER_NAME\SQLEXPRESS] format.

Try using `instance=SQLEXPRESS` after `//localhost:1433` in your URL. For example, `//localhost:1433;instance=SQLEXPRESS`